# Shortest way to add more characters to a string with each successive line

Tags: python, string

I want to write

```
Wow!
Wow!!
Wow!!!
Wow!!!!
... etc
```

in the simplest way possible.

```
print "Wow%s\n"%"!"*3
```

Is as close I can get without a loop (but it doesn't add the exclamations).

If you can't do this in python without a loop, I am curious if there is a language that would allow it.

Comment: What is your definition of "simplest"?

Comment: Least number of characters to specify above output.  Preferably without a loop, but nothing against them!

Comment: shortest I could find: `print '\n'.join('Wow!'+'!'*i for i in range(4))`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.   I was having trouble deciding between your answer and zmbq's (both upvoted), then I was forced to return to bench work and haven't been able to use stack for a few days.

Comment: @user391339 Np, zmbq's ans uses concatenation. I use `format` only because it is recommended (and coz I am used to it). The alternative that I have provided is just for fun and not to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a generator expression (avoiding the loop is not possible)

```
>>> print"\n".join("Wow{}".format('!'*i) for i in range(1,4))
Wow!
Wow!!
Wow!!!
Wow!!!!
```

---

If you really want to avoid `for` keyword

```
>>> n = 4
>>> word = "Wow"
>>> symb = "!"
>>> print("\n".join(map(lambda x:x[0]+x[1],zip([word]*(n-1),map(lambda i:symb*i,range(1,n))))))
Wow!
Wow!!
Wow!!!
```

Comment: Nice trick avoiding the for keyword! OP should be aware there is *still* a loop there, in `[word]*(n-1)`

Comment: @zmbq There are loops hidden everywhere! (sssh, don't tell the OP) :D

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this without some sort of loop, as you need to change the number of exclamation points from 1 to infinity, and for that you need a loop.

You can do that without writing the loop yourself, though:

```
["Wow" + '!'*n for n in range(500000000)]
```

There's still a loop in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your format string like this:

```
print "Wow%s\n" % ("!"*3)
```